# VBScript create function alias for WScript.Echo

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, cmd

I know that it has not any sense. 
But Nevertheless.

I want to create full copy of WScript.Echo

My approach is to create function with another short name.

```
Sub print(arguments)
    WScript.Echo arguments
End Sub
```

In WScript.Echo arguments are array of strings `WScript.Echo Arg1, Arg2, Arg3...  Optional string values to be displayed.` (may be not array, but it looks like list of strings)

My question is how I can pass same argument to my function? Or may be it is not possible in general.

Comment: Are you trying to create a `printf`-style function, where placeholders are replaced with values?

Comment: @Bond If I understand correctly, no. I just trying to create alias to Echo function. Same function with another name, based on Echo. I just calling Echo from my function. Problem is how to pass arguments correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WScript.Echo is a [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) Sub (taking an arbitrary number of arguments). You can't write such Functions/Subs/Method in VBScript. In VBA you can use a [Parameter Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164809%28v=office.10%29.aspx) or the [Optional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164808%28v=office.10%29.aspx) keyword.

For VBScript: You could write a Sub that takes an array a as its only parameter and `WScript.Echo Join(a)`, but I doubt that

```
print Array(...)
```

is worth (1** less letter to type) the effort.

Update: ** Obviously I can't count.

Comment: VBA supports the `Optional` keyword and `ParamArray`. You can use those to create variadic routines. Edit: you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is VBS code that provides the same functionality as `ParamArray` modifier in VBA: it allows to pass arbitrary number of arguments, and called function receives passed arguments as array. It uses ScriptControl JScript `arguments` property to prepare the array of arguments.

```
Dim oSC, Echo

Set oSC = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
oSC.Language = "JavaScript"
oSC.AddCode "echo = function () {var dict = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.Dictionary'); for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {dict.add(i, arguments[i]);} echoArr(dict.Items());}"
oSC.AddObject "echoArr", GetRef("EchoArr"), True
Set Echo = oSC.Eval("echo")

Echo "one", "two", "three"
Echo "True variadic sub"

Function EchoArr(arr)
    WScript.Echo Join(arr)
End Function
```

To call `WScript.Echo` in variadic method manner you can use `Execute`, and replace `EchoArr` function in code above with following code (but I am not sure it has practical value):

```
Function EchoArr(arr)
    Dim s, i
    s = "WScript.Echo "
    i = 0
    For i = 0 to UBound(arr)
        s = s & "arr(" & i & ")"
        If i < UBound(arr) Then s = s & ", "
    Next
    Execute s
End Function
```