# Paramarray in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, paramarray

We have a classic ASP that uses a VB6 COM like this:

```
Dim Value1
Dim Value2
Dim Value3
'Etc.

Dim VB6COM
Set VB6COM = Server.CreateObject("VB6COM")
VB6COM.GetSomeValues MyConnectionString, "TABLE_NAME", "ROW_ID = 1", _
"FIELD_NAME_1", Value1, _
"FIELD_NAME_2", Value2, _
"FIELD_NAME_3", Value3, ... Etc.
```

The procedure being called is like this:

```
Public Sub GetSomeValues(ConnectionString, TableSource, SearchCondition, ParamArray Fields())

  'Code to open the database and retrieve the row goes here.
  'For this example to run without a database, we use example values below.

  For Index = 0 To UBound(Fields) Step 2
    Fields(Index + 1) = "ExampleValue" & Index
  Next

End Sub
```

We want to stop using the VB6COM and move this function to the ASP web site.

So the call should drop the Server.CreateObject lines and end up like this:

```
Dim Value1
Dim Value2
Dim Value3
'Etc.

GetSomeValues MyConnectionString, "TABLE_NAME", "ROW_ID = 1", _
"FIELD_NAME_1", Value1, _
"FIELD_NAME_2", Value2, _
"FIELD_NAME_3", Value3, ... Etc.
```

Problem is, VBScript does not support ParamArrays.

I know we can change the ParamArray to be an array object. But since we have to change thousands of calls, it would be better if there is a way to maintain the original call.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26047731/2165759).

Answer (score 1):

You can use JScript in Classic ASP, which does support variable number of parameters, accessible via the `arguments` 'array'. I can't test it, but I believe you can include the 2 languages side-by-side and call functions defined in JScript from the VBScript.

```html
<script language="JScript">
    // these parameters aren't used directly but they document the positions
    function GetSomeValues(connString, tableName, whereClause, columnName, value /* , ... */) {

        var args = arguments.slice(0), // make arguments a proper array
            ado = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection"),
            connectionString = args.shift(),
            tableName = args.shift(),
            whereClause = args.shift(),
            columns = args; // rest of the arguments are your columns

        ado.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        /* etc */
    }
</script>
<script language="VBScript">
     GetSomeValues MyConnectionString, "TABLE_NAME", "ROW_ID = 1", _
        "FIELD_NAME_1", Value1, _
        "FIELD_NAME_2", Value2, _
        "FIELD_NAME_3", Value3, ... Etc.
</script>
```